# Exclude title and content that are NULL before output in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query and want to exclude title and content that is null. I have tried with `WHERE title IS NOT NULL`, but obviously that didn't work for me and returns error: `Syntax error or access violation`.

The current query

```
SELECT * FROM entries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $postnumbers OFFSET $offset
```

What i tried

```
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $postnumbers OFFSET $offset
```

What is the correct answer?

Table definition

**entries**

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
    content longtext,
    category int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    status int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    keyword1 varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, 
    keyword2 varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    likes varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    image varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    description` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    owner int(30) DEFAULT 0,
    page_views int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    time int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    maincategory int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    entriescol varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=73 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: show us the table definition

Comment: Can you show us the non working query? `WHERE title IS NOT NULL` should work.

Comment: I don't see why the IS NOT NULL should not work. Can you provide the exact query you where running and table definition.

Comment: As @Drejc said we need the exact query and the values of $postnumbers and $offset.

Comment: Has the entries table a title column which is nullable?

Comment: @Drejc default is null.

Comment: @BartłomiejWach Can you clarify? Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "table definition".

Comment: @kanarifugl Write this in database "show create table entries" and paste result here.

Comment: echo the query with the values

Comment: Does this query work: SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title IS NOT NULL, without the order and limit

Comment: @kanarifugl SELECT * FROM entries WHERE title IS NOT NULL ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $postnumbers OFFSET $offset <- what are $postnumbers and $offset? Those look like the problem.

Comment: @OIS Used for endless scrolling to paginate. They work fine as of now. Why would they be a problem?

Comment: @kanarifugl because they are the unknowns in this :) Try removing them and see if it works.